# 2004 ford crown victoria - Fuel Cap pressure

Tags: cel, fuel-system

My check engine light came on yesterday.  with that another little light that says "check fuel cap" also lights up but only stays on for about a second or two.  I have never noticed this before so could this be the reason my check engine light came on?  I need a new fuel cap?

Answer (score 3):

Either a new fuel cap or you have an air leak somewhere in the system. Best to see what the code is first. The computer checks the pressure of the evaporative emissions  system and if it can't hold pressure a code is triggered. Either your cap is bad, a seal is bad/disconnected, etc.